# how to make aspell ignore upper case words (acronyms)?

Tags: emacs, aspell

aspell seems to have some support for filters: http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/4_Customizing.html#filter but I can't find any way to tell it to ignore words that are all capital letters (typically acronyms), which is rather frustrating because my documents tend to have a lot of acronyms.

How can I ignore acronyms in aspell? (or failing that, how can I tell emacs/flyspell not to check upper case words?)

Comment: Looks like adding an option to eliminate acronyms or more generally providing a regular expression to ignore has been suggested to aspell. It is an (open issue)[https://sourceforge.net/p/aspell/feature-requests/58/].  On the emacs flymake side I see where you'd add code to do what you want, and I suppose could monkeypatch that function, i.e. write replacement code for that. Generally though monkey-patching isn't a good idea as it is fragile.